# URL to compose Facebook email/message (compose email via URL-params)

Tags: facebook, email, url

Facebook used to have the following URL format to compose a message:

```
http://www.facebook.com/?compose&id=XXXXXX&message=...
```

However, the above URL does not work any more: it is just forwarding user to Facebook home page. 
Does anybody if it is possible to compose a Facebook email via URL params?

Comment: Is that really on? You're exploiting the user's Facebook cookie to perform an action on their behalf. I guess Facebook want you to use an API for that now where the user can approve or deny your permission to do that.

Comment: @Stack I guess that would / used to take you to the 'send message' page targeting [user 155642845](http://graph.facebook.com/1556452845) with some text pre-entered into the message box, the same as you can with a mailto link. However it may just have stopped working because facebook overhauled their messaging system and the page doesn't exist any more.

Comment: It looks like it's now `http://www.facebook.com/messages/<userid>` (which gets an ajax marker #! inserted when loaded) but no idea if you can fill in the text by default. I'd almost hope you can't, and I'd very much hope you couldn't automatically send the message too at least.

Comment: where can I add message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this link at this moment. User id can be numbers and actual name if the receiver sets it:

http://www.facebook.com/messages/[user id]?msg_prefill=message

It seems this old style works as well. It just redirects.

http://www.facebook.com/inbox/?compose&id=[user id]&message=foo

**Update**
As of November 8, 2012, [Facebook redesigned its Message UI](http://newsroom.fb.com/ImageLibrary/detail.aspx?MediaDetailsID=2764) and msg_prefill nor message parameter no longer works.

Comment: It bugs me why this answer hasn't been accepted yet. Pay it forward Robert.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if it helps, but I use:

```
https://m.me/<PAGE_ID or USER_ID>
```

It links to the Facebook Messenger.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be informed on changes, [a bug was opened](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487654884599869?browse=search_5095c1201b8a67b63835059) on Facebook on October 26, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two options for a Facebook message link generation:
https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/[USER_ID]
or
https://m.me/[USER_ID]

Answer (score 0):

This mobile link still works:

https://m.facebook.com/messages/compose?ids=USER_ID

As of May 2015, I have not found a desktop link that works.