# Send a Facebook message on a dektop/mobile website

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, message

I want to give users a button to send a link via Facebook message to their friends. For dektop devices, there is the send dialog, which works great: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

As stated in the documentation, it doesn't work on mobile devices and just throws an error. Things get further complicated because some users have the Facebook App installed and some don't.

The perfect solution would be along:

1. Try to send the message via the app. I found `fb://messaging/compose` but could not find a way to prepopulate it with a link.
2. If that fails, send the message via the mobile website. I couldn't find anything for that.

The next best thing would be to share the link, instead of sending a message. I tried http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com, but that doesn't open the app, even if it is installed.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: For iOS and Android, there’s the Message dialog.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the Message dialog from a website? The Facebook Doc just has examples for native apps.

Comment: You can’t, that’s for native apps only.

Answer (score 1):

The way to send private messages on your website is making a link going directly to facebook message page.

> http://www.facebook.com/messages/[user_id]

Check out this answer. They got the same problem. [URL to compose Facebook email/message (compose email via URL-params)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879854/url-to-compose-facebook-email-message-compose-email-via-url-params)

Comment: While this link may answer the question it is highly discouraged to post link only answers as the links may expire in future.Try quoting some thing useful from link so that it may help even if the link expires